# Delivery is delayed errors, seems specific to Office 365 recipients

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-office-365

Our site runs SBS 2011, with Exchange 2010.
We have recently changed ISP and made the necessary changes to Exchange connectors, static IP, reverse DNS and MX (phew). All inbound and outbound mail seems to be fine, except....
We are now seeing delivery delayed errors, consistently to correspondents who run Office 365. The server tells us it is trying for a day or so, but the email ends up never getting there at all.
Have checked and cannot see our domain listed on blacklists (Spamhaus, Trend Micro etc.)
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You need more details related to the exact reply given by Office 365 servers. Graylisting is not used by the cloud so it is definitely not that.

Do you have a full NDR or something in the smtp logs?
As a last resort, you can create a test Office 365 tenant and send a couple of emails, afterwards check the message trace in the cloud ECP.

Answer (score 0):

With the current detail, it's a guess, but I seen report that from Office 365 some enterprise got problem to receive their mail because on how the email is sent, as some router / antispam feature on your side can badly close the connection.

Like that KB for Cisco ASA, that when inspection is On it fail; http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/113423-asa-esmtp-smtp-inspection.html

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, what does the NDR say?
Additionally, while the email is in Queue on your server, what is the response that you get from Office 365?